# Sticky div work incorrect

Tags: jquery, sticky

I made sticky div with this script -

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var leedoffset = $('.leed_block').offset().top;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= leedoffset) {
        $('.leed_block').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.leed_block').removeClass('sticky');
    }
})
```

But when div goes sticky, offset top has been always less than window scroll because its always in visible part of page. 
So, what i have do ?

Comment: whats the value of variable `leedoffset`? it is greater than zero right? and what's the CSS dec for class `.sticky`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the `leedoffset` outside the **[`scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll%5C/)** handler, otherwise it will get updated on each scroll event.

```js
var leedoffset = $('.leed_block').offset().top;
// otherwise it will become `0` after position changed

$(window).scroll(function() {
  console.log(leedoffset,$(window).scrollTop());
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > leedoffset) {
    $('.leed_block').addClass('sticky');
  } else {
    $('.leed_block').removeClass('sticky');
  }
})
```

```css
#main {
  height: 1000px;
}
.leed_block {
  margin-top: 250px;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top:0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="leed_block">
    div
  </div>
</div>
```

If screen resize is causing problem then you can do something like this with the help of **[`resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)** handler

```js
var leedoffset = $('.leed_block').offset().top;
// otherwise it will become `0` after position changed

$(window).scroll(function() {
  console.log(leedoffset, $(window).scrollTop());
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > leedoffset) {
    $('.leed_block').addClass('sticky');
  } else {
    $('.leed_block').removeClass('sticky');
  }
}).resize(function() {
  leedoffset = $('.leed_block').removeClass('sticky').offset().top;
  // check updated value after removing sticky class
  $(window).scroll();
  // trigger scroll event for updating
});
```

```css
#main {
  height: 1000px;
}
.leed_block {
  margin-top: 250px;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="leed_block">
    div
  </div>
</div>
```

You can simplify the if else statement using **[`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)** with flag

```js
var leedoffset = $('.leed_block').offset().top;
// otherwise it will become `0` after position changed

$(window).scroll(function() {
  console.log(leedoffset, $(window).scrollTop());
  $('.leed_block').toggleClass('sticky', $(window).scrollTop() > leedoffset);
}).resize(function() {
  leedoffset = $('.leed_block').removeClass('sticky').offset().top;
  // check updated value after removing sticky class
  $(window).scroll();
  // trigger scroll event for updating
});
```

```css
#main {
  height: 1000px;
}
.leed_block {
  margin-top: 250px;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="leed_block">
    div
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update :** As per your comment you can do something like this

```js
var leedoffset = $('.leed_block').offset().top;
// otherwise it will become `0` after position changed

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($('.leed_block').is(':not(.sticky)'))
  // get the offset only if the sticky class is not added  
    leedoffset = $('.leed_block').offset().top;
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > leedoffset) {
    $('.leed_block').addClass('sticky');
  } else {
    $('.leed_block').removeClass('sticky');
  }
})
```

```css
#main {
  height: 1000px;
}
.leed_block {
  margin-top: 250px;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="leed_block">
    div
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, declare offset top outside window scrolling function work as well. But i have other problem: in top of site i have fotorama slider, that have absolute position elements, and my offset top don't calculate right (block start scrolling early than we scroll to it).

Comment: @user2486902 : updated answer... check the last snippet

Comment: Strange but its work!) My offset is wrong at start, but when i redeclare them in scroll function, it start work as well) Thank you anyway, but its strange for me.

Comment: Oh, also i see, when i scroll down the leed_block, and refresh page - offset.top goes wrong start position, and sticky class is added so its dosent redeclare new offset when we scroll and .leed_block scroll top upper than we need.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn’t need to work with very old browsers (like Internet Explorer) or very exotic ones (see [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky)), there is no need for JavaScript anymore:

```css
#main {
  height: 1000px;
}
.leed_block {
  margin-top: 250px;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* needed for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="leed_block">
    sticky div
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the downvote? My solution works (please *Run code snippet* to check) and the Internet Explorer is even deprecated by Microsoft.